# Comparing list of objects to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects and I want to compare a string(actually int but I can cast it to str) to check of any of the object in the the list has that string as a member.

Now there is way in which I can iterate over all objects and compare `val1` member with my string, but I was wondering if it is possible to do the way below?

```
class Check:

    def __init__(self, val1):
        self.val1 = val1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val1)


o1 = [Check(100)]
test = "100"

for x in o1:
    print(x)
print(test in o1)
```

but the `print(test in o1)` return `false`

Comment: Is it always in `val1`?

Comment: yes it is always val1

Comment: Then why not simply do `test == x.val1` in the for loop

Comment: its a list of objects

Comment: You should work with `__eq__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may overide the `__eq__` operator, in case the `other` parameter is a string, be nice also to keep a comparison to another `Check` object

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, str):
        return other == str(self.val1)
    if isinstance(other, Check):
        return other.val1 == self.val1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because your method returns a string representation which is equal to the string representation of some other object does not make those objects compare equal.

If you wanted instances of your class to be treated as equal to other objects that have the same string representation, then you could add an `__eq__` method that implements this:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other)
```

You will then find that in your test case that `test in o1` evaluates `True`.

Note that if you do this then `Check(100) == Check('100')` will also evaluate `True` (even though their `val1` properties are of different types).  You do not specifically say whether you want this, but the fact that you want `Check(100) == '100'` to evaluate `True` strongly suggests that this is this case.

Answer (score 0):

Full working example with `typing`.

```py
from typing import List


class Check:
    def __init__(self, val1: str or int):
        self.val1 = val1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val1)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        comparison_type = str

        if not isinstance(self.val1, comparison_type):
            self.val1 = comparison_type(self.val1)

        if not isinstance(other, comparison_type):
            other = comparison_type(other)

        return self.val1 == other


if __name__ == "__main__":
    o1: List[Check] = [Check(100)]
    test: str = "100"
    print(test in o1)
```

Answer (score 0):

O1 consists of a list of instances, since you instantiate the Check class, and you're comparing it to a string, which of course won't work. Test is a string object, while the one object o1 contains is, on the other hand, a Check object (that's what type() would return if you ran it on it).

Note that `__str__` has nothing to do with turning the object into a string: it's simply used for 'pretty printing' (eg as done by the print function) and is called by `print()` when ran on the given object, which is contrast to `__repr__`, which is, conversely, meant for more of a raw, technical, implementation-related display.

Something else needs to be overloaded for the object to support comparisons and in order to define exactly how it should behave in such situations: ie `__eq__` and `__ne__`.